# How to make Details component not increase width when content is wider than summary text and state changes to opened?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using `Details` component and want to add some content to it (usually a text that is slightly longer than detail's summary text). However, when details is opened, content overflows details width, which increases overall width of details, which is unwanted behavior.

Code:

```
val details = new Details("Short summary",
                new Span("Very looooooooong text that is wider than summary." +
                            "This span can even be wrapped in layout component like vertical layout"));
```

Example:

When closed:
[image: closed state of details component]

When opened:
[image: opened state of details component]

Using vaadin 24.

Comment: Have you tried `details.setWidth(....)`?

Comment: @kscherrer Sure I can hardcore px sizes, but not applicable if I have 20 details with different summaries. I would need to calculate or measure somehow in advance. Plus, width might be different with different browser font sizes.